# Error SSL/TLS al hacer un Git push

Tags: git, github, ssl, git-bash, tls

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Git y al intentar hacer un git push para agregar los archivos a mi repositorio remoto me salta el siguiente error

```
fatal: Error al enviar la solicitud.
fatal: Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS.
```

Y cuando ingreso mi nombre de usuario y contraseña me aparece lo siguiente:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/Proyecto-Integrador---xxxxx-xxxxx.git/'
```

Aclaro que anteriormente vincule el repositorio con la URL y agregue el token de acceso que creé en github. Ya desisntalé y volví a instalar el programa pero no encuentro soluciones que me funcionen. También alcaro que utilizo un equipo viejo de 32 bits con Windows 7.

Comment: Que version de git estas usando?  `git version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GitHub actualizó su forma  remota para autenticación de contraseña.
> ahora usar PAT (`token de acceso personal`) para autenticarse

[token acceso](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/)

> Posicionado en tu proyecto en Github: Crear un Token personal  seleccionando los ítems adecuados de acuerdo a tu interés

Setting-->Developer Setting---->Personal Acces Token
--->Generate New Token

> Windows OS: En tu windows yo uso W10

Panel de control-->Administración de credenciales --> credenciales de windows -->
credenciales genéricas --->`git:https://github.com`--

> > Editarla de forma que la contraseña será tu Token de acceso Si no existe crearla agregando credenciales genéricas Luego al hacer
> > pull/push `sin credenciales` GitHub debería consultarte para  logearte introducir en contraseña tu token
> > Tambien revisa

:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de utilidad?

Comment: Hmm, uso los tokens y igual me sale ese mensaje error, ahora me pide ingresar usuario y contraseña